# Saving a generated EXCEL file from HTML into the server with ASP

Tags: html, excel, file, asp-classic

I have a page that makes a file from a HTML for download with this piece of code:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=teste.xls"
```

Is there a way using classic ASP to save the file into a specific folder in the server instead making the client download it?

Answer (score 1):

You can save a file on the server in Classic ASP using the Scripting.FileSystemObject object. Here's an example for making a text file:

```
<%
dim fs,f
set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
set f=fs.CreateTextFile("c:\test.txt",true)
f.write("Hello World!")
f.write("How are you today?")
f.close
set f=nothing
set fs=nothing
%>
```

Comment: it didn't work

it won't save the file that was created with the Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"

Comment: How are you creating the Excel file at the moment -- are you just Response.Writing comma or tab separated values? Did you change the file name created to .xls or .csv instead of .txt? Note that it won't be possible to save the file in native XLS format, it will have to be a CSV or tab delimited file.